# select2 4.0 - always add option to remote data results

Tags: jquery-select2-4

I am giving the 3.5 -> 4.0 upgrade another go and 'almost' have this use case working like it was.  What I am stuck on now is how to ALWAYS add a certain option to the ajax results list.

Here is what I have right now :

**html:**

```
<select id="vedit-filter" name="settings[filter]" class="form-control select2">
    <option value="default" selected="">default</option>
</select>
```

**js:**

```
$("#vedit-filter").select2({
    placeholder: "Select or enter application...",
    allowClear: true,
    multiple: false,
    tags: true,
    ajax: {
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 1000,
        type: 'post',
        url: '/process/get_application_list.php',
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                term: term, // search term
                page_limit: 25, // page size
                page: page // page number
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
            var more = (page * 25) < data.total; // whether or not there are more results available
            return {
                results: data.results,
                more: more
            };
        }
    }
});
```

That will load 'default' as the initial selected option.  If the user changes this then it is gone.  I want a way for them to revert back to that initial selection if need be.  Is the only way to include it in my returned results from ajax as an option?  Or is there a way to do this on the js side?

**UPDATE:**

The default selection will always be dynamic, but in this example we are using a value/name of 'default'.

```
<select id="vedit-filter" name="settings[filter]" class="form-control select2">
    <option value="default" selected="">default</option>
</select>
```

then in the js:

```
var default_filter = $("#vedit-filter").val(); //get the default loaded from the html

placeholder: {
  id: default_filter, // or whatever the placeholder value is
  text: default_filter // the text to display as the placeholder
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently [explained this on GitHub](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3294#issuecomment-101384493) but didn't realize how much of a breaking change it was.

> I want a way for them to revert back to that initial selection if need be.

Select2 provides the `placeholder` option, which can allow you to specify a placeholder like "Select an item" to the user if a selection is not already made.  In order to support a `<select>`, which will select the first option by default (that's done by the browser), Select2 requires that a "placeholder" `<option>` exists. This also doubles as the option which Select2 uses to determine if the placeholder needs to be displayed.

In addition to the `placeholder` option, Select2 also allows the user to remove their selected option, which will revert the selection back to the placeholder option. This can be enabled through the `allowClear` option.

> Is the only way to include it in my returned results from ajax as an option? Or is there a way to do this on the js side?

In your example, you are using a placeholder option with a `value` set on it. Because Select2 expects that the `value` is blank/empty by default, you need to tell Select2 what to look for when detecting the placeholder. This can be done by passing a data object into `placeholder` which Select2 will use when checking.

```
placeholder: {
  id: 'default', // or whatever the placeholder value is
  text: 'Select or enter application...' // the text to display as the placeholder
}
```

This will tell Select2 to display the placeholder when the `value` is set to `default`, which in your example appears to be the placeholder/default option.

> What I am stuck on now is how to ALWAYS add a certain option to the ajax results list.

While I think we might have solved [the XY problem here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/159034), I did want to note that adding a new option to the AJAX results list is as simple as overriding `processResults`. This is because `processResults` passes the list of data objects directly to Select2, which gives you a safe place to inject new options into the list.

You just need to `.push` the extra data object into the `results` and then pass them back to Select2.

Comment: Thanks Kevin... I made a small update above.  This correctly shows 'default' (in this example) as the placeholder and will revert back to it on clears. I found one issue though.  When the search returns no results I return `$ajax_result['results'][] = array('id' => 0,'text' => 'No results found...');` which tells the user there were no results for their search.  Clicking on that reverts back to my 'default' placeholder, but now it no longer has a value associated with it.

Comment: @user756659 Are you able to actually control whether or not the "No results" item is returned? I'd recommend just returning an empty array and letting Select2 manage that notice, that way you don't need to worry about users selecting it.

Comment: Yes, it is my own script... I tried returning an empty array, but then I ran into the issue where the 'notice disappears because I have tags enabled to allow their current search term to be selected.  So in other words, whenever they search there will always be an option and in turn doesn't show the 'no results' notice.

Comment: The other option is to not include an `id`, so Select2 won't register it as an option that can be selected.

Comment: PERFECT - that works and displays the message along with everything else I needed to do.  I assumed the `id` would be required with `text`.  Thanks!